# My subfloor has been built with untreated 1x2s and plywood. Am I in trouble?

Tags: flooring, floor, subfloor

Last year a contractor installed about 800 square feet of sub flooring to even out the very uneven concrete floor. At the time I didn’t think of it, but the fellow used standard 1x2s and plywood. I’m lucky enough that there isn’t any water infiltration (no sediment deposits around fissures in the concrete floor), but I’m wondering if this is going to be a problem for me down the line.

So the question is...what do I do now? I've already built walls on top of the subfloor, so completely removing the floor is going to be a hard ask. Any ways around that?

Comment: This is all non-structural work done in a basement?

Comment: This isn't an answerable question. It's entirely a matter of prerogative and the details of your contract. (It's _code_ that wood in contact with concrete be treated or isolated. Did your contract explicitly or implicitly require that code be met?)

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming this is all non-structural work done in a basement due to the work that was done.

> what do I do now?

Nothing.

If it doesn't experience any issues in your/the house's lifetime (40+ years), you've won.

If it fails, you'll have to tear out and redo it, but that is basically the situation you are already in if you want to do anything to build a better system.

Keep track of the humidity and use a dehumidifier if needed to keep the humidity at an appropriate level.